# python wx AUI Notebook , add page that is tiled

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

im doing a little program with server/clients and using python wx.aui_notebook,

i want to add a notebook page on every client that join in, i do it but the problem is
that the page is like docked/folded .. (i hope i use the term right)
what i want is that the new page that was add will be shown in screen and will take for example half of the space available,

screenshot 1 is what happening,
screenshot 2 is what i want to happened (i did this one manually and i want it to be automatically)

screenshot 1:

[image]

screenshot 2:

[image]

thanks for help,

jack

Comment: I believe what you want is a `wx.SplitterWindow`

Comment: not exactly, i still wanted the option to move windows/hide some, this AUI_NOTEBOOK is exactly what i want(some pages can be folded back and some shown to the user)   i just want that when a page is added, it wont be automatically on back(or folded back) but will shown as in screenshot 2

Comment: screenshot 2 looks like a splitterWindow to me...